# Program is running but I get error when the user inputs integers

Tags: java

My program runs but I'm getting an error `String index out of range: 3` When I enter `1 2` for example. I tried changing the values of `1` in `partStr = str.substring(lastSpace + 1, x);` but that didn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str;
    int x;
    int length;
    int start;
    int num;
    int lastSpace = -1;
    int sum = 0;
    String partStr;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a series of integers separated by spaces >> ");
    str = keyboard.nextLine();
    length = str.length();
    for (x = 0; x <= length; x++) {
        if (str.charAt(x) == ' ') {
            partStr = str.substring(lastSpace + 1, x);
            num = Integer.parseInt(partStr);
            System.out.println(" " + num);
            sum += num;
            lastSpace = x;
        }
    }
    partStr = str.substring(lastSpace + 1, length);
    num = Integer.parseInt(partStr);
    System.out.println(" " + num);
    sum += num;
    System.out.println("         -------------------" + "\nThe sum of the integers is " + sum);
}
```

Comment: At which line do you get that error?

Comment: `for(x = 0; x < length; x++)` - valid string indices are `0` to `length() - 1`. You are calling `str.charAt(str.length())` which is one character too many.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

You should traverse upto length - 1.

The indexing in String is similar to what happens in arrays.If the length of String is 5 for example,the characters are stored in 0-4 index positions.

Your current loop is traversing beyond the size of the string.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I tried changing int lastSpace = =1; to 0 but it's still out of range?

Comment: Change your loop condition to x < length,that should get rid of the error you are facing now.

Answer (score 1):

**str.length()** will return the amount of characters of the string, let's say **N**

**for(x = 0; x <= length; x++)** will loop **N+1** times, instead of **N**, because the index starts at 0 and you also enter the loop when x is equal to the length

replacing **<=** with **<** in the for loop will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

The issue you faced is because you tried to access a character at the index, `x` (i.e. `str.charAt(x)`) from `str` where `x` is beyond the maximum value of the index in `str`. The maximum value of the index in `str` is `str.length - 1` whereas the `for` loop is running up to `str.length`. In order to fix that problem, you need to change the condition to `x < length`.

However, even after fixing that issue, your program may fail if any entry is non-integer or if there are multiple spaces in the input. A clean way, including exception handling, to do it would be as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a series of integers separated by spaces >> ");
        str = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Split str on space(s) and assign the resulting array to partStr
        String[] partStr = str.split("\\s+");

        // Iterate through partStr[] and add each number to sum
        for (String num : partStr) {
            try {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(num);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Integer::parseInt will throw NumberFormatException for a non-integer string.
                // Display an error message for such entries.
                System.out.println(num + " is an invalid entry");
            }
        }

        // Display the entries and the sum
        System.out.println("Your entries are: " + Arrays.toString(partStr));
        System.out.println("The sum of the integers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a series of integers separated by spaces >> 10 a 20 10.5 30 b xy 40 
a is an invalid entry
10.5 is an invalid entry
b is an invalid entry
xy is an invalid entry
Your entries are: [10, a, 20, 10.5, 30, b, xy, 40]
The sum of the integers is 100
```